# How to handle Bower components images, fonts or other assets (with yeoman)?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I'm building a webapp using yeoman. Everything is great except the fact that I'm getting a bit confused with using assets (like images or webfonts) that are bundled with some bower components (sass-bootstrap for example...)

I include javascript assets using Requirejs, but my main problem lies with the images and fonts... What's the right approach? Can't seem to find it anywhere... Should I copy all the font files to the font directory I use with compass? Those files wouldn't be updated when the bower component is updated...

Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy, use your bower_components directory as another assets directory like scripts or styles. Link to it in your requirejs paths, and link to it in your compass config.

If you want, during your build you could look into your bower folders and copy all images and/or fonts into other subdirectories in your dist location.

You made a good point, copying source files won't get updated when you update. That's why you want to try as hard as you can to just leave them as is.

Comment: The problem is that compass' config doesn't allow multiple paths for fonts/images... And I obviously can't have my app's styles in the same directory as the bower components...

Comment: You only want Compass working with images that you've added, for instance building sprites. You don't need Compass to handle vendor images and fonts, just use the grunt copy task to move any images and fonts not handled by Compass from bower_components into your dist directory along side your source files.

For styles, just include them in your sass file... for example: 
`@include "../bower_components/font-awesome/sass/font-awesome.scss";`